# WiFi Adapter Not Found in 18.04 on XPS 13 9360

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, xps

I've been using my XPS 13 9360 under 18.04 for quite a while now, but as of a few days ago, Ubuntu is no longer detecting my wireless adapter. I've tried googling for a solution, but nothing I've tried has worked. I updated my kernel to 5 in hopes of it fixing, but it's still bricked.

Here's the output of `lshw -C network`:

```
-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: enp0s20f0u2c4i2
   serial: 1e:5c:f2:1b:68:b2
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.4 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Here's the output of `rfkill -all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

And the output of the wireless-info tool:

```
########## wireless info START ##########
Report from: 24 Oct 2019 22:56 EDT -0400
Booted last: 24 Oct 2019 00:00 EDT -0400
Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000
##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description   : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release       : 18.04
Codename      : bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

i3

##### lspci #############################

3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

dell_laptop            20480  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,dell_laptop
wl                   6447104  0
ath                    32768  0
mac80211              774144  0
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
wmi_bmof               16384  0
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
cfg80211              679936  3 wl,ath,mac80211
compat                 16384  2 mac80211,cfg80211
sparse_keymap          16384  3 intel_hid,dell_wmi,intel_vbtn
wmi                    28672  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       835     1  0 22:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/225 Boyos]] (600 root)
[connection] id=225 Boyos | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=225 Boyos
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/darlington but 5G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=darlington but 5G | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=darlington but 5G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/I Sit When I Pee]] (600 root)
[connection] id=I Sit When I Pee | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=I Sit When I Pee
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Free_Library]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Free_Library | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Free_Library
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/psu]] (600 root)
[connection] id=psu | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=psu
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR27-5G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR27-5G | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=NETGEAR27-5G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR04]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR04 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=NETGEAR04
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/tusecurewireless]] (600 root)
[connection] id=tusecurewireless | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=tusecurewireless
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VodkaInMyEverClear]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VodkaInMyEverClear | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=VodkaInMyEverClear
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     00D38A27B7E3C7B97C238FC
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       5.0.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     6718DD3F72A13EAE989B5CA
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       5.0.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
srcversion:     588F160BC95B7B3A96275C2
depends:        cfg80211,compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/cfg80211.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     BCF157A5337A326CC2937B9
depends:        compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.0.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  206.020459] ath10k_core: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_ie (err -2)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Each time I run `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci`, it outputs:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

And the accompanying `dmesg` output is:

```
[ 1675.516951] ath10k_core: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_ie_match (err -2)  
[ 1675.517491] ath10k_core: Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_ie (err -2)  
[ 1675.519284] ath10k_core: Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_vendor_ie (err -2)
```

I've also tried running `sudo modprobe cfg80211_find_ie_match`, which gives the output:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module cfg80211_find_ie_match not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic
```

Does anyone know what else I can do to try to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**: Here is the output of `dpkg --status linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic`:

```
Package: linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 8585
Maintainer: Canonical Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux-signed-hwe
Version: 5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2
Provides: aufs-dkms, fuse-module, ivtv-modules, kvm-api-4, linux-image, redhat-cluster-modules, spl-dkms, spl-modules, virtualbox-guest-modules, zfs-dkms, zfs-modules
Depends: kmod, linux-base (>= 4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1), linux-modules-5.0.0-32-generic
Recommends: grub-pc | grub-efi-amd64 | grub-efi-ia32 | grub | lilo, initramfs-tools | linux-initramfs-tool
Suggests: fdutils, linux-hwe-doc-5.0.0 | linux-hwe-source-5.0.0, linux-hwe-tools, linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic
Conflicts: linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-32-generic
Description: Signed kernel image generic
 A kernel image for generic.  This version of it is signed with
 Canonical's UEFI/Opal signing key.
Built-Using: linux-hwe (= 5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2)
```

**UPDATE**: I was apparently halfway between 18.04 and 19.04, so I've upgraded completely to 19.04 in an effort to fix the problem. However, I get the exact same lshw output, as well as the same modprobe errors in dmesg. I'm about to just do a clean install at this point unless if someone has any bright ideas.

**FINAL UPDATE**: I resorted to ordering a new wifi card (the Intel 8265) after unsuccessfully fixing my drivers for the killer 1535 card that the XPS 9360 comes with. Booted up, and wifi works flawlessly now.

Comment: This looks like a kernel bug. Or the kernel is not fully installed.

Comment: Uninstall the iwlwifi backports and reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 I just uninstalled the backports, and it gave me a note that said I may or may not need to update my initramfs. "You should if any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs." How do I check these and what are they?

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated my post with the dpkg output to check the kernel status. Does this look alright? Could it still not be fully installed?

Comment: Just reboot and it should work

Comment: Are linux-modules installed?

Comment: initramfs should be updated after backports uninstall.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I did reboot and it is still in the same position unfortunately. @Pilot6 I'm working on the reinstall of my linux-headers right now. I'm concerned that a new issue is that I only partially updated my Ubuntu to 19.04 last night before cancelling the install as I didn't want to use all of my mobile data (tether) to download it all. I'm running apt upgrade right now, and everything is coming from the disco repository, i.e. `Get:261 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 netbase all 5.6 [13.0 kB]` Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on my Dell XPS 15 9570 running the 5.0.0-37-generic kernel in Ubuntu 18.04.

As [churrov2](https://askubuntu.com/users/1009127/churrov2) experienced

- `lshw -C network` returned the `-network UNCLAIMED` message for the QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
- `dmesg` showed the `Unknown symbol cfg80211_find_ie_match` and `Unknown symbol ieee80211_bss_get_ie` errors

I did what [Jeremy31](https://askubuntu.com/users/300665/jeremy31) suggested above in the comments and ran

```
apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

and rebooted Ubuntu and the problem was solved